# How does bass music make vibrations?

Tags: theory

Please explain to me how bass music from one house makes another house vibrate, they are roughly 10 feet apart.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: All sound **is** vibrations. When vibrating air contact something that is not vibrating, some of the vibrational energy is transferred.

Comment: Please look up resonance in a suitable physics book.

Comment: @MS-SPO Resonance is not required for sound to rattle things

Comment: @ToddWilcox, that‘s an interesting statement to a physicist ;-) Honestly, damped resonance is exactly in the realm of waves, vibrations etc.

Comment: @MS-SPO I believe the point here is that sound waves will cause objects to vibrate even if the frequency isn't particularly close to any of the object's resonant frequencies.  It's sufficient to note that sound waves are periodic changes in pressure and that these will cause the house to move.  There's no need for discussions of resonance.  Those will be useful to explain why e.g. the floor shakes more when the bass plays G than it does when the bass plays F.

Comment: Ok, from one house to an other, some distance apart, there are two possible pathes: through soil and through air. With the source involved, bass instrument, air will be more effective than soil. So you have one box (house 1) with vibrating air, travel through air, second box with air. This is resonance phenomena at its best. Why won‘ a flute (higher frequ.) do the same as a bass? Wavelengths, room dimensions, resonance. // I‘ll drop from this discussion now.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - surely that's the whole point of sympathetic resonance - if something vibrates at a pitch which doesn't match another, or its harmonics, it isn't affected?

Comment: @Tim Resonance involves vibration, not all vibrations are resonance. When a bomb or an earthquake goes off, things move back and forth but not necessarily in harmonic motion and there can be no sympathetic resonance with an impulse. Some may point out that many object will resonate after a bomb or earthquake. My point is that not **all** motion is resonance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a useful question

Comment: @ToddWilcox if there weren't some resonance in the house structure, the energy transfer would be far less -- as  is the case for the higher frequencies

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Yes there **is** resonance from delta functions such as a bomb-blast shockwave.  Do a Fourier decomposition and you'll find energy content at the frequencies under discussion.

Comment: @MS-SPO "Why won‘t a flute (higher frequ.) do the same as a bass? Wavelengths, room dimensions, resonance." A big factor in this situation is the wildly different coefficients of reflection and absorption of building materials between low and high frequencies. Diffusion also makes a difference. A cubicle wall in an office building does not enclose a resonant air volume but does attenuate and reflect high frequencies fairly well and does almost nothing to low frequencies.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, you make me break my word? So be it. First, watch the response function depending on losses. Notice asymmetry for f=0 (sub-bass) and f=inf (flute) . Bass will be at resonance, see room dimensions https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Resonance.PNG // Here‘s the 2 house situation, tuned to the right „vibration“ https://vid.puffyan.us/watch?v=5H8aRCyEGnU . // Bye.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's fundamentally a physics question rather than a musical one.

Answer (score 2):

The exact same way it vibrates your eardrums, and the way high pitched sound can break a glass.  Sound is pressure waves - normally in air, but the waves can travel through walls and windows too.  Walls, windows, and air will all absorb some of the sound, each absorbing different amounts at different frequencies.

High frequency waves dissipate faster than the low frequency waves, so, by the time the sound reaches the house next door, the bass will be stronger than the treble.  Especially if some of that house's building materials have a resonant frequency that matches the bass frequencies, the windows (for example) will rattle!

Comment: Dispersion at that distance is not a significant factor